# How to prevent Wavesurfer.js stopping playback with click on waveform?

Tags: javascript, wavesurfer.js

I have a wavesurfer player (https://wavesurfer-js.org/) with (a working) play/pause-Button and waveform. **Goal: a click on the waveform continues playback from the new position, if player is running.**
Right now a click on the waveform of the running player causes the player to pause.
The progress is moved correctly to the new position and a hit on the play-button starts the playback from there.
I can capture the (undocumented by wavesurfer) click-event

```
myWaveSurfer.drawer.on('click', e => {
      myWaveSurfer.play();
    });
```

but this does not seem to do the trick. I already tried `e.preventDefault()`.
Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that this is related to the bug that was introduced in version 4.2 ([issue on Github](https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js/issues/2149)). Version 4.4 is supposed to include a fix, so I'd suggest updating or reverting to 4.1.

If updating is not an option, simply calling `play()` on the `seek` event seems to work even though `isPlaying()` returns true already. It feels a bit hacky since it's not the intended behavior, but here's an example:

```js
wavesurfer.on('seek', () => {
  if (wavesurfer.isPlaying()) {
    wavesurfer.play();
  }
});
```

Comment: I am a bit unsure regarding the version - I just grab it from unpkg (should be the actual version, though it is labelled with 1.3.4, which is definitely not the wavesurfer version running).  But your code is working just fine - thank you for pointing me in the right direction.